# How to push a data in array in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to post a data and it will return a list. But that list can't push into an array.
I tried below code:

```
var a=data.Data;
$scope.cont.push(a);
angular.forEach($scope.cont, function(todo) {
    $scope.datalist.push(todo);
});
```

But can not find the solution

Comment: Looks fine, what have you tried? Add some `console.log(..)` statements and see what the values are. What is your html code? How are you seeing that nothing is happening? Do you have other bindings working? etc. etc.

Comment: s i am trying to bind the list into the html like below...

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="contact in datalist track by $index">
                <td>
                    {{ contact.name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ contact.email }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{contact.phone }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{contact.id }}
                </td>
               
            </tr> but can not bind the valus in that list

Comment: did you try without `track by index`? Create a demo in plunker that replicates problem

Comment: i tried it earlier but no change

Comment: won't get much help unless you provide a demo that replicates problem. Use [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit) or jsfiddle.net